# catch specific string inside single quote using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Inside my configuration file located in `${BBPATH}/conf/local.conf` I have the following variable:

```
MACHINE ??= 'myboard'
```

I want to do a bash script that select `myboard` from this file file and assign it to a variable `MACHINE`.

So far I tried the following without success:

```
": ${MACHINE:=$(sed -n -E "s/MACHINE \?\?= '(.*)'/\1/p" ${BBPATH}/conf/local.conf)}"
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with GNU `sed`:

```
MACHINE=$(sed -nE "s/^MACHINE \?\?= '(.*)'/\1/p" "${BBPATH}/conf/local.conf")
echo "$MACHINE"
```

Output:

```
myboard
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the syntax of `bash`. This is nowhere near `bash` syntax. In bash this would probably be something like:

```
MACHINE=$(sed -n "s/'//g;s/MACHINE.*= *//p" ${BBPATH}/conf/local.conf)
```